# Replace values in dataframe without using *_join

Tags: r

I'd like to know if there's a way to replace values in a column in a dataframe based on a external dataframe, without joining them. Here's an example of what i mean:

Let's say I have this external df:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"),
                 b = c("x","y","z"))
```

If I want to replace values in iris data, I usually do:

```
iris %>% 
  left_join(df, by = c("Species" = "a")) %>% 
  select(-Species) %>% 
  rename(Species = b)
```

I think there's a way to do something like:

```
iris %>% 
  replace(Species, df$b, by = df$a)
```

This is just an example. For my real data, i cannot use `case_when` or `fct_recode`, as my data are quite a lot and not factors.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate post, we can use a lookup vector, match on names: `iris$Species <- x[ setNames(c("x","y","z"), c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")) ]`

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks, but this doesn't work, as it considers the arguments as columns and not rows

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, try again: `x <- setNames(c("x","y","z"), c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")); iris$Species <- x[ iris$Species ]`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! If it is a duplicate, feels free to vote to close this question